# Is there a way to use Methods in Structured Text (ST) to program a PLC

Tags: plc, structured-text, iec61131-3

So I am new to PLC programming and I come from a traditional Object Oriented programming background. I am used to programming languages having guides/references on how to use the languages but I cannot find any readily available online.

I want to use methods to program this PLC in Structured Text, but I do not know how to. Is there any way I can write a method in ST?

Answer (score 2):

With the release of the 3rd Edition of the IEC61131-3 by PLCopen there are object oriented extensions included.

These extensions are already available on many PLC platforms.

Structured Text is just a part of the IEC 61131-3 languages. And indeed I recommend it as the first choice if you come from another C-like language (with or without OOP). You can use it very well with OOP.

Main feature of the OOP extension :

A FunctionBlock is like a class and can extend (derive from) another FunctionBlock and implement multiple Interfaces and it can have Methods and Properties (get/set) that can all be defined via Interfaces

Don't code your Structured Text programs using traditional procedural programming techniques, if you don't want!

Comment: Where can I get this document? I can't find any hints of an actual reference document at PLCOpen.